# Android 5.1 on emulator always offline

Tags: android, build, adb, emulation

I build Android 5.1.51 and try run it on Emulator. But adb always shows that device offline and after 2 minutes list of devices becomes empty.

build target is aosp_x86-eng

Camera not work.
Internet not work too.
Gallery always crashes

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What emulator are you working with?

Comment: AVD. Sdk tools 24.1.2

Comment: Try using a new emulator like [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/download), if you want how to install see [this](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/developers/user-guide), let me know if it works :)

Comment: I need to use AVD.
I forked it and added some function

Comment: Then try to re-install the emulator

Comment: When I use prebuild system image of Android 5.1 from SDK, adb work fine

Comment: It look like it https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=79433

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:
It works fine when replace kernel-qemu to new version